Angular Keycloak using pkceMethod S256 Error and not able to display data
Im new here with Keycloak angular..
I am facing these error and not able to understand and debug.
ERROR undefined:

Zone - Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ app.module.ts:98
Promise.then (async)
8835 @ main.ts:6
webpack_exec @ main.ts:7
(anonymous) @ main.ts:7
(anonymous) @ main.ts:7
(anonymous) @ main.js:2

I am able to get my access token on keycloak:
access_token
: 
"eyJhbnR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJWa2hpXzB5UWhIeFptRGxCcmhzcU45ams3STRKeGRJd2pTYzBDcjZYcUQwIn0.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.VOJajj_UQP0GKSLq_MWwxxmaZu-g8zavX170AbROKhErw55r1EcXC_FhYW3cxJjoP7TJn3fRN499ZvJPNeFX9gkYHuQbLvlxPvb69TX7aOAg-w0nFG7wkoWyuKYNbLNaZGajxiLKO4d-gomrRBdIfyrrAwdwnzuZB-r1oQl_t4UHnvvmmV46fzvdN2T45AWIF3W7DT7uiorAAhUYwhlA5E4oMXFcgYSIno2VInXouH2m87HNxPa6pRifoirTXoebNxa1GTpZknzLgqogvc1AIsXrALSkhIxwXHdK8jNk5duz-dUgTPgG10N2JXM3PC9EZDRTRvlQdTvLaRJw_6fnXg"
expires_in
: 
300
id_token
: 
"eyJiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJWa2hpXzB5UWhIeFptRGxCcmhzcU45ams3STRKeGRJd2pTYzBDcjZYcUQwIn0.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.uHMWGpsSwnaedZo22ItJ0Hjs1s4yQThHdcq-w2X811rhO5qsWtMf5X5Eq1h2pqQtuAJHwOXVKhLJnfplSEMqT5S9boBZMZ7h7FYDpcbaTbRgvnuM6H3TvWBi-4XOE2CGXnVRJVb1G-pHjbC-qMhbVLwbUrbE05KZlBlEUl7Os7C2Ob47BFBEGlCF6zuGH48j0nf5qgts0clj-u-36jGlt702I25HbsKDK_b2tpiV5vXIH2a0JCR5ikiLhYLmWNboUfqIjL8Xmc2WKHUhkkrnOtm003zYNetAe7ZgJscu65IuGKUrbSIVKXtn3ViXy1EveVmoGXM1BVBM9roy-ecKWg"
not-before-policy
: 
0
refresh_expires_in
: 
1800
refresh_token
: 
"xMiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIzYmZjMjlmNi1mOTRmLTQ2MDgtYTk0ZS0xOGFkZTRjMGIyYzUifQ.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.onWuJtVaH8QBjWjsnuoZ0pFXVmDPJ_BXKqKbdDadA3LW4v5Q4Imnemw-deDPfGpXRh84U4eZF8mb7UoxI_uxjA"
scope
: 
"openid profile email"
session_state
: 
"f88a60-fc93-402a-bbb0-c2dee5bfe568"
token_type
: 
"Bearer"

Below is my configurations:
ng version
Angular CLI: 15.2.10
Node: 16.13.0
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 15.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.11
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.10
@angular/cdk                    15.2.9
@angular/material               15.2.9
@schematics/angular             15.2.10 (cli-only)       
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.8.4</kbd>

app.module.ts:
import { KeycloakAngularModule, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
    return () =>
        keycloak.init({
            config: {
                url: 'http://localhost:7080/',
                realm: 'realm-data',
                clientId: 'client-id-data'
            },
            initOptions: {
                pkceMethod: 'S256',
                redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
            },
            loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false
        });
}

...
..
.
providers: [
        provideAnimations(),
        DatePipe,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
            multi: true,
            deps: [KeycloakService]
        }
    ],

app-routing module ts
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'home',
        title: 'Home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthKeyClockGuard],
        data: {
            roles: ['ADMIN']
        }
    },

..
.
auth route ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { KeycloakAuthGuard, KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { KeycloakProfile } from 'keycloak-js';
import { LoginUser } from '../model/class/authenticateModel/login-user';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthKeyClockGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
    user = new LoginUser();
    public userProfile: KeycloakProfile | null = null;
    constructor(protected override readonly router: Router, protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService) {
        super(router, keycloak);
    }

    public async isAccessAllowed(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        // Force the user to log in if currently unauthenticated.
        console.log(this.authenticated);
        if (!this.authenticated) {
            await this.keycloak.login({
                redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url
            });
        } else {
            this.userProfile = await this.keycloak.loadUserProfile();
            console.log(this.userProfile);
            this.user.authStatus = 'AUTH';
            this.user.firstName = this.userProfile.firstName || '';
            this.user.email = this.userProfile.email || '';
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('userdetails', JSON.stringify(this.user));
        }

        // Get the roles required from the route.
        const requiredRoles = route.data['roles'];

        // Allow the user to to proceed if no additional roles are required to access the route.
        if (!(requiredRoles instanceof Array) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }

        // Allow the user to proceed if all the required roles are present.
        return requiredRoles.some((role) => this.roles.includes(role));
    }
}

Hoping somebody could help me solve this error.
I tried changing init on keycloak but still the same. Tried also changing config on Keycloak admin. And also try to find on other issues with similar error but failed.

Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. Edit the question and include code fragments.
